# freeradius execute script on accounting

Tags: radius, freeradius

i am using freeradius2, i would like to extract data from one of the radius attribute which is sent on Accounting-Request.

can you advise what parameters needs to be in the accounting section so that i can execute a script and extract the radius headers?

```
    accounting {
            acct_unique
            detail

        #update request {
           #execute script here
}

            sql_accounting
            attr_filter.accounting_response
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update request {
    Tmp-String-0 := `/my/script "%{hex:Attribute}"`
}
```

Your script can then parse the hexits which get passed and return a correctly formatted attribute.

Comment: Note this will only work in FreeRADIUS >= 2.2.1 (that's when the hex: xlat function was added).